# Por que no puedo ver las clases de mi sub elemento?

Tags: javascript

pude resolver el problema de codigo que tenia, sin embargo por  curiosidad me di cuenta que no podía poner las subclases de mis elementos child solo las clases del father. Se puede resolver?

Como puedo lograr invocar las subclases sin que me arroje el undefined?

```
class Media {
  constructor(title) {
    this._title = title;
    this._ratings = [ ];
  }
  get title() {
    return this._title;

  }
}
  
class Book extends Media {
  constructor(author, pages, title) {
    super(title);
  }

  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }

  get pages() {
    return this._pages;
  }

const SouthAmericaStory = new Book(
  "Gabriel Garcia",
  32,
  "El general no tiene quien le escriba"
);
   

//esto lo imprime //
 console.log(SouthAmericaStory.title);
//////////////////////////////////////

//esto no //
 console.log(SouthAmericaStory.author)
/////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no estás asignando las propiedades de la clase hija. Con llamar a `super()` no basta. En las clases hijas debes asignar aquellas propiedades que no son del padre.

```js
class Media {
  constructor(title) {
    this._title = title;
    this._ratings = [];
  }
  get title() {
    return this._title;

  }
}

class Book extends Media {
  constructor(author, pages, title) {
    super(title);
    /*
       author y pages son de la clase hija
       así que deben ser asignadas aquí
       a diferencia de title que sí es del padre
       y por ese se le pasa al padre con super
    */
    this._author = author;
    this._pages = pages;
  }

  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }

  get pages() {
    return this._pages;
  }
}

const SouthAmericaStory = new Book(
  "Gabriel Garcia",
  32,
  "El general no tiene quien le escriba"
);


//esto lo imprime //
console.log(SouthAmericaStory.title);
//////////////////////////////////////

//esto también //
console.log(SouthAmericaStory.author)
console.log(SouthAmericaStory.pages)


/////////////////////////////
```

**PD**: Era coronel, no general. :)